# How can I print JasperPrint directly to printer?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I use *Java* to create report with *JasperReports*. What i want to do is that user be able to print directly, without print dialog.
I create *JasperPrint* and I know name and model of my printer.

I have also looked in the [sample here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/printservice/index.html) but could not figure out how.
I use *Java 1.7* and latest *JasperReports* library.

**Does anyone know how to do it?**

```
public class PrintApp  {

    public static void print() {
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = getJasperPrint();
            String printername = AllPrinter.getDepartmentPrinter("Admin");
             // where should i introduce my printer name to jasperreports?
            JasperPrintManager.printReport(jasperPrint, false);
    }

    private static JasperPrint getJasperPrint() {
            return JasperPrinterCreator.getJasperprint();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks relevant:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/1758399

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I solved it as below, hopefully it helps someone else.**

```
public class PrintApp  {

    public static void print() {
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = getJasperPrint();
            String selectedPrinter = AllPrinter.getDepartmentPrinter("Admin");

            PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
            PrintService selectedService = null;

            if(services.length != 0 || services != null)
            {
                for(PrintService service : services){
                    String existingPrinter = service.getName().toLowerCase();
                    if(existingPrinter.equals(selectedPrinter))
                    {
                        selectedService = service;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(selectedService != null)
                {
                    printerJob.setPrintService(selectedService);
                    boolean printSucceed = JasperPrintManager.printReport(mainPrint, false);
                }
    }

    private static JasperPrint getJasperPrint() {
            return JasperPrinterCreator.getJasperprint();
    }
}
```

Comment: this will be printed on the client side printer ?

Comment: You're printing mainPrint, I assume this should be jasperPrint?

Comment: what import to use to include the AllPrinter cause it gives me an error "Allprinter cannot be resolved"

Comment: Doesn't work with CUPS PDF 
and i think doesnt work in general as well should not be the selected answer please test with a multi printer setup

Answer (score 1):

```
private void PrintReportToPrinter(JasperPrint jp, String impresora) {
    try {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        // printRequestAttributeSet.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4); //setting page size
        printRequestAttributeSet.add(new Copies(1));

        PrinterName printerName = new PrinterName(impresora, null); //gets printer

        PrintServiceAttributeSet printServiceAttributeSet = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet();
        printServiceAttributeSet.add(printerName);

        JRPrintServiceExporter exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();

        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jp);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printRequestAttributeSet);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printServiceAttributeSet);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PAGE_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
        exporter.exportReport();
    } catch (JRException ex) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cancelo Impresion");
    }
}
```