# JasperReport with spring MVC : print report on client side without displaying it

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, printing, jasper-reports

I am developping a Spring MVC - Angularjs application.
I need to print reports, I chose JasperReport to do that.

Before I move on, I want to know if I can generate a report, then directly print it on the default printer set up on the client computer (printer which can change according to users) **without displaying** it on screen.
I have been looking for answers on this specific need, but couldn't find any.

If anyone knows about it....

Source to generate report and print it:

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
params.put("Title", "My Report");

InputStream reportStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(TEMPLATE); 
JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load(reportStream);
JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, params, datasource.getDataSource());

JasperPrintManager.printReport(jp, false);
```

Comment: Have u tried some code to achieve this ? Add it to ur post.

Comment: No, because my dev server is actually on local (same computer as the client), for development purposes. I can't use a server on a different computer for now. And I believe that this could be a problem.

Comment: Do u want Java code to generate report in some format or print Or both ?

Comment: you can see a sample code on my post. I want to direct print it (the display format would be PDF for example). Basically it would be a PDF output that would be printed without previewing it on screen.

Comment: See my answer. I hope it solves ur problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an object in HTML page which hold PDF & then print it using `print()` method or use `java.awt.print.PrinterJob`. See below examples.

- [Print embedded PDF from browser with Javascript, HTML5, AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877165/print-embedded-pdf-from-browser-with-javascript-html5-angularjs)
- [Print a PDF from the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205180/how-to-print-a-pdf-from-the-browser)
- [Print PDF directly from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239513/print-pdf-directly-from-javascript)
- [Print JasperPrint directly to printer ? - Java PrinterJob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361919/how-can-i-print-jasperprint-directly-to-printer)
- [Different examples using java.awt.print.PrinterJob](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=java.awt.print.PrinterJob)

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks! seems like I ll have to embed javascript in my PDF with Jasper. That should work fine. My ultimate goal is to silent print this pdf, but after a few hours of search, it seems that it's impossible.

Comment: Welcome. Good to know your problem has been solved with this.